# Magento 1.9.2 custom admin grid redirects to 404 error page

Tags: php, magento

I want to add order items grid in the sales section of the admin panel

I am following the below link for the same 
[How to Add a Custom Table to Magento Admin Backend](http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/adding-custom-table-magento-admin-interface)

I am getting the menu as order items in sales => order items but when I click on the order items  Link to goes to 404 error page

following  is the code in my config.xml file

```
<config>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <sales>
            <children>
                <order_items translate="title">
                    <title>Order Items</title>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/order_items/index</action>
                </order_items>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

I have added Ikantam_KnowledgeBase.xml file in app/etc/modules folder which contains the following code :

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Ikantam_KnowledgeBase>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Ikantam_KnowledgeBase>
</modules>
```

i was not able to see the menu until I added this file in the above mentioned location . which was not given in the tutorial .

Now I am able to create the menu but the menu takes me to 404 error page.

The tutorial also mentions adding the following code in the configuration file

```
<config>   
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <knowledgebase before="Mage_Adminhtml">Ikantam_KnowledgeBase_Adminhtml</knowledgebase>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

when I added the above code to the config.xml files code the order items menu disappeared .

I am very new to Magento ,I  have no idea where this code should be added.
Any Help will be Highly Appreciated.

Comment: You're missing XML declaration tags at the start of all your config files, and you're missing the closing `</config>` tags as well

Comment: @robbieAverill  i have added the XML  deceleration and closing </config> tag still the same issue . where should i add the code in the mentioned in the last coding section of the question.